# Weird White box appears on my custom multiselect . On inspection I realised it has to do something with overlow scroll

Tags: html, reactjs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGiYR.png) I am working on react js for my website. Weird white box on my custom multi select appears only in chrome (Checked with Safari and firefox). It has to do something with overflow-y : scroll as removing this line makes website working fine.

```html
            <div className={headerClass}>

                        { isEmptyList(value) ? null : 
                            <> {   value.map(value => (
                                    <Chip 
                                        key={value} 
                                        label={value} 
                                        className={classes.chip} 
                                        onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(value)}
                                        size='small'
                                        color='default'/>)) } </> }

                        <input  className={styles.value} 
                                value={query} 
                                onFocus={() => query == label && this.setState({query : ''})} 
                                placeholder={label}
                                onChange={ event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
                                style={inputActive ? {color : TEXT_COLOR} : {}}>
                        </input>

            </div>
```

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.54);
}
```

```html
           <div className={headerClass}>

                        { isEmptyList(value) ? null : 
                            <> {   value.map(value => (
                                    <Chip 
                                        key={value} 
                                        label={value} 
                                        className={classes.chip} 
                                        onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(value)}
                                        size='small'
                                        color='default'/>)) } </> }

                        <input  className={styles.value} 
                                value={query} 
                                onFocus={() => query == label && this.setState({query : ''})} 
                                placeholder={label}
                                onChange={ event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
                                style={inputActive ? {color : TEXT_COLOR} : {}}>
                        </input>

            </div>
```

Comment: Have you some code to show us ?

Comment: My site was working well on chrome but not in safari and firefox. There was some margin-top issue in safari and firefox. I added `reset.css` and it was all fixed. https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6